# Different string for specifed post type on posts listing at homepage

Tags: wp-query, query, listing

I use below code to list custom post types on homepage beside standard posts

```
    <?php $args = array('post_type' => array( 'post', 'gallery_posts' )); ?>
    <?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
    <?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
        <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
            <?php _e('Read More', ''); ?>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

What i should to do for change 'Read more' text for second type of post while looping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the post type in a conditional and echo a different 'read more' text based on this.

Your `$query` is a `WP_Query` object and has a `$post` property. This is a `WP_Post` object of the current post and it has a `$post_type` property.

You can access it directly with `$query->post->post_type` to check the type.

So your code would be something like:

```
<?php $args = array('post_type' => array( 'post', 'gallery_posts' )); ?>
<?php $query = new WP_Query( $args ); ?>
<?php if ( $query->have_posts() ) : ?>
    <?php while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>
        <?php if ( 'post' === $query->post->post_type ) : ?>
            <?php _e('Read More', ''); ?>
        <?php elseif ( 'gallery_posts' === $query->post->post_type ) : ?>
            <?php _e('View More', ''); ?>
       <?php endif; ?>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

References:

- `get_post_type()`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_type/
- `WP_Query`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/
- `WP_Post`: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Post